# Reflexive sheaves and determinants

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. I just recall some notions, for my question below to be clear.

Let $F\in\textrm{Coh}(X)$ be coherent of rank $r$. If it is torsionfree, it has a well-defined determinant line bundle $\det F=(\Lambda^rF)^{\vee\vee}\in\textrm{Pic}(X)$. If $r=1$, then $\det F=F^{\vee\vee}$. Furthermore, $F$ is torsionfree iff the natural map $F\to F^{\vee\vee}$ is injective, and is said to be reflexive iff that map is an isomorphism.

It follows:

*Fact*. A reflexive rank one sheaf $F$ on $X$, such that $\det F=\mathcal O_X$, is necessarily $\mathcal O_X$ itself.

Let $I\subset \mathcal O_X$ be an ideal sheaf. Then $I$ is torsionfree of rank one, so it embeds into its double dual $0\to I\to I^{\vee\vee}=\det I$.

*Question*: why is $I^{\vee\vee}=\mathcal O_X$?

I believe I should use the *Fact*, but I do not see why $I^{\vee\vee}$ should be reflexive with trivial determinant.

It is obviously reflexive because it is a line bundle, and it actually *is* its own determinant, but why is it trivial?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I notice now that all the previous comments have disappeared. I did not mean, by my question, to give rise to such a devastation :)

Comment: Why do you define det$F:=(\Lambda^rF)^{\vee\vee}$? In Vakil's notes, for example, he defines det$F:=\Lambda^{\text{rank}F}F.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while since this was posted, but I'd like to note that the reason it is hard to show is that it is false.  If $I$ is the ideal sheaf of a codimension $1$ subvariety (say $X$ is projective), then the determinant is not trivial: $I$ is reflexive, and $\det I = I$.

If $I$ is the ideal sheaf of a subvariety of codimension $\geq 2$, then the result is true.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So if $I$ is an ideal of a codimension $\geq 2$ subvariety, then $I^{\vee\vee}=\mathcal O_X$ is true, right? But does it follow from the *Fact* or from what?

Comment: It should be straightforward to show that the first dual is trivial.  The point is that the zero locus of a regular function has codimension 1.